# Cannot deploy ear package when there is to many web modules inside

Tags: ejb-3.0, payara, java-ee-8

I've created ear app on payara server. There is an ejb package and some web modules. Everything was fine till I added a new web module.

I have an error message that says in my EJB jar there is no EJB class which is not true. When I have less than three web modules then everything works fine, but when I add new modules the error occurs again.

```
SEVERE:   Exception while parsing file file:/Users/mikolaj/Documents/programowanie/NetBeansProjects/pstdio_services/pstdio_services-ear/target/gfdeploy/pstdio_services-ear/
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@735ef671 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@60f1aa16[Running, pool size = 20, active threads = 8, queued tasks = 30, completed tasks = 243]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.parse(Parser.java:293)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleJar(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:197)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

WARNING:   result fault org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$Result@1e051c19 Result for /Users/mikolaj/Documents/programowanie/NetBeansProjects/pstdio_services/pstdio_services-ear/target/gfdeploy/pstdio_services-ear/
SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [pstdio_services-ear]
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ejb jar [pstdio_services-ejb-1.0.jar]: it contains zero ejb. 
Note: 
1. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style), or message-driven bean. 
2. EJB3+ entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and please package them as library jar. 
3. If the jar file contains valid EJBs which are annotated with EJB component level annotations (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven, @Singleton), please check server.log to see whether the annotations were processed properly.
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:643)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.visit(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:767)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:121)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:643)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.validate(ApplicationArchivist.java:723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:268)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:934)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:874)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because Payara Server processes the EAR asynchronously in several threads using the Payara Executor Service. It looks like you're using Payara Server 5.184 or older which has the queue size limited to 30 by default and then it stops accepting more tasks, which results in the rejected exception. You should set the queue size to a higher value with the command [set-payara-executor-service-configuration](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/payara-server-5.191/nucleus/payara-modules/payara-executor-service/src/main/java/fish/payara/nucleus/executorservice/admin/SetPayaraExecutorServiceConfigurationCommand.java). The default value was set to 500 in version 5.191: https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/3497